# How to output DateTime type to table storage in Azure function with Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, datetime, azure-functions

I am using Node.js to write a Azure function and want to output a column with DateTime to a Azure storage table.

I tried the following way but nothing is working:

- `{ date: '2017-01-02T03:04:05.000Z' }`
- `{ date: new Date('2017-01-02T03:04:05.000Z') }`

Comment: So what is the problem that you get?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like we currently support this from node. I've opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1203

Comment: Thank you very much! I will follow it.